# Wordpress send the url the registration form was filled out at as part of the email

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a wordpress site with two registration forms on it, they are located on two different pages via "theme my login" short code. I would like to be able to track which of the form's the user submitted the registration form on, I'm thinking via the admin email that notify me there is a new user or even as a field as Im using Cimy user extra fields, my question is 
1) are either of these options possible
2) which is quicker / easier to achieve as It has to be done asap
3) can you point me in the right direction for guides or even the codex if its that simple.

im guessing the I would need to find the hook in wordpress that is responsible for the admin email and add the wordpress either `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or a wordpress equivilant?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the url of the page which you embed the form, in the email. You can use hidden input field if you have used a custom form. If you have used contact form 7 plugin, you can get needed information [from this url](http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

Comment: due to other requirement's of the site it has to be a member registration form on the page so they instantly become a user of the site, not contact form 7?

Comment: So, why don't you pass page title or page url as a hidden field when the form submits?

Comment: how would I do this? I understand the concept in simple HTML put wordpress plugin customisation is a little beyond me! sorry